# Active Directory LDAP error return string

Tags: active-directory, ldap

when I bind to Active Directory with LDAP and something is wrong with the account I typically get the following error string:

> LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 533, v1db1

The first part is the general LDAP 49 error (as per standard), the second is the Active Directory specific error (and this is documented). What I could not find is an explanation of the third bold part - v1db1 in this case.

Depending on the directory I use, I typically get v1db1, vece, or v893. Any idea of what that means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code "data 533" implies [ERROR_ACCOUNT_DISABLED](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors).

Enable the account and try again.

-jim

Comment: Hi Jim, my question is around the third part of the error message. What is the meaning of v1db1? Thnx